# how to add a custom input dialog to current Window?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, modal-dialog, user-input

There's a current window with number of cells. On double click event trigger, an input dialog to be opened get the user input.

Created a new usercontrol (xaml) and added following info. 
[image]

I found a [solution in C#](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/creating-a-custom-input-dialog/), but this has to be done in VB.net code for WPF. Other than the approach stated in this link, are there better approaches that can be followed to create my own input dialog?

Comment: Maybe you could try a [C# to VB.Net converter](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+to+VB.Net+converter&oq=C%23+to+VB.Net+converter).

Comment: What exactly is your question. If you've already created the window then you will already have the skeleton of the vb code file. VS will add all the methods for the clicking and double-clicking for you as you add the events to the xaml file. Then you just have to implement them.